# Summernote is displayed at all positions(laravel 5.2)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, summernote

I am working on laravel 5.2 .When i click on "Edit Group Name", summernote text editor is displayed below each groupname as shown below [image]

I want that the summernote text editor is displayed only for the particular group name.

My view:

```
    @foreach($groups as $group)

   <div  id="zx" class="panel-content">
   <div class="row">
   <section  class=" col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-3">
   <img id="imagecircle" style="width:40px;height:40px; 
   margin-top:5px;background-color:silver;" 
   class="img-circle" src="images/g.jpg"/>
   </section>
   <section class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-6 col-xs-8">
   <a id="hash" href="" style="font-size:20px;
   text-decoration:none;">{{$group->name}}</a>
   <textarea  style="display:none;" name="textfield4" 
   id="textfield4">  </textarea>
   <div class="groupname" id="a"></div>
   </section>


   <section class="col-md-1 dropdown">
   <button type="button" style="margin-top:5px;"
   class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   <span id="removesign" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
   </span></button>

   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
     <li role="presentation"><a style="font-weight:bold; 
    color:black;" onclick="edit()" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Edit Group Name</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a style="font-weight:bold; color:black;" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="{{ URL('/groups/'.$group->id) }}">Leave This Group</a></li>

  </ul>


   </section>

   </div>
   </div>
  @endforeach
```

My js code:

```
   var edit = function() {
   $('.groupname').summernote({focus: true});
    };
```

Comment: Ithink because you selector is a class `$('.groupname')` and all of the groups has the same class !